# it is possible one c# program run in multiple accounts

Tags: c#

Hello anbody help me on this 
 iam using one account for create c# application.my account created in windows nt in my system. i asusally run that regularly
now iwant to run this program from multiple accounts in my system(local mechain),becuase this application run by shift system.
what to do

Answer (score 1):

You probably want one of the following:

1. Install the program so that all users see it.  This means a proper install into Program Files and adding a shortcut for all users.
2. You want to create the program as a windows service, that will run without a user even being logged in
3. You want a combination of both.